# Location problem

Tags: security, location

I recently began using Ubuntu about 2-3 weeks ago and have encountered a significant issue with my location settings. When I check my physical location on my laptop, it shows me in a completely different place compared to my phone, which is on the same network and displays the correct location.

Any assistance or tips would be greatly appreciated. I suspect this might be a security-related problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Does your laptop have GPS hardware installed in it?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Have you turned location services on? [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1498070/edit) and add the answers to all the questions we ask in comments.

Comment: silly question perhaps but are location services even turned on? https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/privacy-location.html.en